# Is it possible to run SharePoint 2013 on SQL Server using Compatibility Level 120

Tags: 2013, sql-server

I need to migrate a SQL Server 2014 instance supporting SSAS/SSRS and SharePoint to SQL Server 2016.

Unfortunately, I won't be able to have separate instances.
I've read that SharePoint 2013 isn't compatible with SQL Server 2016 but Can't find if running in Compatibility Level (120) is possible.

I would really appreciated some feedback if you have tested this setup.

Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ronalg/2016/06/13/sharepoint-20132016-and-sql-server-2016-supportability-with-ssrs-fun-facts/, SharePoint 2013 will never be supported to run on SQL 2016 for its database storage, so running it on SQL 2016, even with a lower compatibility level will not be supported.

While it may in practice work okay (I've not tried it yet), that combination will not be supported, and should you have any issues, Microsoft will not provide you with support and help.

I'd strongly discourage you to run this combination in production.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work smoothly because lowering the compatibility will not convert the sql server to lower edition, it will change few things within the database level.

Moreover, if you manage to run it but it's not gonna supported by the Microsoft. I would highly discourage to run that in production farm.

Comment: Thank you for this Comment. I'm well aware of this but I'm still looking for feedbacks.